# How to connect two devices behind router

Tags: sockets, networking

```
Device A -> Router -- Internet -- Router <- Device B
```

I know VoIP normally direct connect two device. But I don't know how they get connected. I assume there's a server on internet.

For others have questions like me:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two routers are doing NAT, then yes, probably there is a server in the middle.  So, each device only has to make a connection OUT through the router, which is no problem.  Then the server can pass data back and forth between them.

But it is also possible to make a connection directly, even if both routers are doing NAT.  In order for this to work, at least one router needs to have a port forwarding configuration set up, to allow an inbound TCP connection from the other to be forwarded to the correct device, on some specific port.  This port forwarding could be manually configured on the router or it could (depending on the router) be set up automatically by the device, using UPnP protocol (if the router supports it).

Even then, usually there's a server in the middle that both devices might communicate with to find out the IP and port number used by the other device.  But if you have other ways of knowing this information, it's not necessary.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Select the best answer. I'll use UDP hole.

Answer (score 0):

I assume since you mention VOIP you are wondering how two IP Phones connect?

Phone is configured with the IP address of a PBX. Phone 1 makes a call. The digits are sent to the PBX. The PBX examines the phone number dialed and looks up the phone number in something called a dial plan. That dial plan tells the PBX the path to get to the phone number dialed. It may say open a connection to the phone company or it might tell the PBX the IP address of the other PBX.

If it gets the IP address of another PBX it sends a SIP message to the remote PBX informing that it has a incoming call. The remote PBX accepts the SIP message and sets up the call and tells the remote phone to ring. When the phone is answered the two IP PBX's agree that the call is set up and tells each phone the ip address of the other phone and allows them to communicate directly.